# Confused on examples of basic functions in C

Tags: c, function, reference

I've just started with C and am following along in ["The C Programming Language"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628).

In the first chapter I found something that seems quite strange for me (I've done a lot of work in higher level code like JS, Python, C#). What I'm referring to is this snippet that reads input, analyses its length and then copies it if longer than previous:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int get_line(char line[], int limit);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);


int main () {

    int len, max;
    char line[MAXLINE], longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;

    while((len = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) { // <-- here
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy (longest, line);
        }
    }

    if (max > 0) {
        printf("Longest string: %sLength: %d\n", longest, max);
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_line(char line[], int limit) {

    int current, index;

    for (index = 0; index < limit -1 && (current = getchar()) != EOF && current != '\n'; ++index)
        line[index] = current;

    if (current == '\n') {
        line[index] = current;
        ++index;
    }
    line[index] = '\0';
    return index;
}

void copy (char to[], char from[]) {

    int index = 0;

    while ((to[index] = from[index]) != '\0')
        ++index;
}
```

The strange thing in this snippet is how the parameters in the function calls to `get_line` and `copy` seem to be references (even though they aren't pointers?).

How for instance is `line` and `longest` values the same in `main` as in the helper functions even though `main` is missing any scanner and none of the helper functions returns the character arrays.

Comment: Array name stores base address of that array, which means you are passing address.

Comment: Ah, cheers! Makes a lot more sense now! :)

Comment: @Sniper "Array name stores base address" is not quite right... the compiler knows where the array should be much like it knows where a plain `int` should be, but the array doesn't hold the address of its elements.  In most situations where you use the array name, you get a pointer to the first element instead -- but it's not stored in the array (kind of like how using `&` with an `int` gives you a pointer to the `int` even though the `int` variable doesn't store that address).